# Parsing an array in Kusto QL - extracting a specific value

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I am trying to parse the data from LoggedOnUsers column and **extract a value of 'UserName' field**. My query gives me an empty field as a result.

`DeviceInfo | extend field=todynamic(LoggedOnUsers) | project user=field.UserName, LoggedOnUsers | top 1 by LoggedOnUsers`

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7pj9.png)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `LoggedOnUsers` value is an **array** of objects, so to extract the `UserName` you need to first extract the first item in the array, like this:

```
let DeviceInfo = datatable(LoggedOnUsers:dynamic) [
    dynamic([{"UserName":"gospodarz","DomainName":"VTEST2-PG","Sid":"S-1-5-21-1814037467-..."}])
];
DeviceInfo
| extend user = tostring(LoggedOnUsers[0].UserName)
```

Result:

| LoggedOnUsers | user |
| --- | --- |
| [ { "UserName": "gospodarz", "DomainName": "VTEST2-PG", "Sid": "S-1-5-21-1814037467-..." } ] | gospodarz |

If the array may contain multiple entries (and all have the same structure), then you'll have to use `mv-expand` first:

```
let DeviceInfo = datatable(LoggedOnUsers:dynamic) [
    dynamic([{"UserName":"gospodarz","DomainName":"VTEST2-PG","Sid":"S-1-5-21-1814037467-..."},
             {"UserName":"another_user","DomainName":"VTEST2-PG","Sid":"S-1-5-21-1814037467-..."}])
];
DeviceInfo
| mv-expand LoggedOnUsers
| extend user = tostring(LoggedOnUsers.UserName)
```

Result:

| LoggedOnUsers | user |
| --- | --- |
| { "UserName": "gospodarz", "DomainName": "VTEST2-PG", "Sid": "S-1-5-21-1814037467-..." } | gospodarz |
| { "UserName": "another_user", "DomainName": "VTEST2-PG", "Sid": "S-1-5-21-1814037467-..." } | another_user |

Also, looks like you want to get the username that appeared most times by using `top`, however you're trying to run `top` on a dynamic column, which is invalid. Instead, you first need to count the number of times every username appears, and then apply `top` on this number. This is how you do it:

```
let DeviceInfo = datatable(LoggedOnUsers:dynamic) [
    dynamic([{"UserName":"gospodarz","DomainName":"VTEST2-PG","Sid":"S-1-5-21-1814037467-..."},
             {"UserName":"another_user","DomainName":"VTEST2-PG","Sid":"S-1-5-21-1814037467-..."},
             {"UserName":"another_user","DomainName":"VTEST2-PG","Sid":"S-1-5-21-1814037467-..."}])
];
DeviceInfo
| mv-expand LoggedOnUsers
| extend user = tostring(LoggedOnUsers.UserName)
| summarize count() by user
| top 1 by count_
```

Result:

| user | count_ |
| --- | --- |
| another_user | 2 |

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive answer. However, my final goal is to extract UserName from LoggedOnUsers 'dynamically', i.e. without pasting data to be parsed in the query itself (without this: ([{"UserName":"gospodarz","DomainName":"VTEST2-PG","Sid":"S-1-5-21-1814037467-..."}])), please ignore 'top' operator, since I only added it to limit the number of rows in the query result.

Comment: All you have to do is delete the `let DeviceInfo = ...` from my queries. I only wrote these to show you how the query would work on synthetic data. Once you delete the `let DeviceInfo = ...` thing from my queries, the queries will run on your actual `DeviceInfo` tables. Give it a try :)   By the way, if you only want several arbitrary records, then you should use `| take 10` instead of `top ...` - this is much more efficient.

Comment: Great, it's working now. Thank you for your help.